# How to instance classes with readonly attributes

Tags: c#, class, language-features, instance, readonly

I want to create an instance of the [`AudioFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.audioformat%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class from all the required information.

Basically, what I have is

- `int` BitsPerSample
- `int` Channels
- `int` SamplesPerSecond
- [`WaveFormatType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.waveformattype%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) WaveFormat

The problem is, that simply using something like

```
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat();
format.BitsPerSample = BitsPerSample;
[...]
```

doesn't work, since `Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Media.AudioFormat.BitsPerSample' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`.

Is there an easy way to create such an object? If not, what should I do to create it? Using inheritance, overriding the properties so that they have setters? Creating an XML representation of the object and then deserialize it? Using some other ugly hacks (no `unsafe` :-) )?

Comment: By the way, these are _properties_, not attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to create this class directly.
It exists to return information from the `AudioCaptureDevice` class, from the `SupportedFormats` property, using an internal constructor.

If you're trying to use it for your own purposes, you should create your own class.

Comment: So, then how am I supposed to transmit an instance of `AudioFormat` over a TCP socket? Currently, I'm taking the four members which are needed to reconstruct it, to reduce overhead of serializing it completely into xml etc. Currently, it is only 16 bytes.

Comment: You aren't supposed to.  You should create your own class.